# Update values during delayed button press

Tags: java, android, button, delay

essentially I am making a single player game where if the user doesn't press a button in a certain amount of time then they lose. If the user wins an alert dialog box comes up notifying them they won the round. The way i programmed it is that there is a secret button that gets pressed after 1500 ms, the problem is when the user wins a dialog pops up indicating they won, but then another dialog box pops up (1500 ms later) indicating they lossed right after. i tried using the following code to prevent that second dialog box from popping up, but its not working and at this point im kind of stuck. So the main question here is how do  i update values after a button is delayed pressed.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        button2_.performClick(); // the delay
                    }
                }, 1500);

                        //  skip some code 

                            if (!alert.isShowing())   // check if dialog box is open
                            {                         

                                alert.show();
                            }
```

Comment: dint get your question do you ant alert box to be shown after your delayed button function process complete?

Comment: When an alert box is showing I don't want another alert box to show. The thing is, for some reason on the delayed button click it doesn't process values after the 1500 ms. Therefore even though a alert dialog box Is showing it doesn't notice it.

Comment: Instead of checking whether the alert is showing, you can try introducing a boolean variable that will be false if user doesn't click the button and check against that.

Comment: I've tried using a boolean statement too, it's just this delayed statement thing is giving me an issue. At runtime it's not processing any current values after 1500ms, so even if I have a boolean statement if I change it to true between 1500ms it still reads it as false